# Which is better for SEO, redirecting to specific page or home page?

Tags: seo, redirects

I have two websites: www.mainwebsite.com and www.otherwebsite.com, but the latter will no longer be used so I'd like to redirect it. In www.mainwebsite.com, I have a page www.mainwebsite.com/other that is related to www.otherwebsite.com. I know that for UX, I should redirect www.otherwebsite.com to www.mainwebsite.com/other. But for SEO, is it better to do this or redirect to the home page?

Comment: Why are you questioning whether what is good for UX is not also good for SEO?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Search engines like contextually sound redirects. They have indexed your old site and know the content. If you redirect it to the home page, which may not have contextually similar content, you may actually get less of a boost, in the end, than if you redirect to a fitting page on your new site. And of course, it's also better for UX, no question.

What it comes down to is, are you going to bulk redirect your whole old domain to the main one, or are you going to take it page by page, or category by category? If you bulk redirect, I recommend redirecting to the page that makes sense, not the home page. However, if you're willing to do more work and redirect pages and categories individually, you can do your SEO some good by spreading it around. So you'd still redirect most of your pages to the specific page on the new site, but you might redirect some of your old pages to the home page, contact page, maybe other pages too. That would be better for your SEO, and hopefully your users too.